Continuous map : homeomorphism = ? : homotopy equivalence
I was studying topology when a question came to my mind.
In topology, one studies continuous functions and then those particular ones called homeomorphisms, which somehow induce a symmetric relation between their domain and their codomain, since the inverse of a homeomorphism is itself a homeomorphism. (I am aware that, given two non-empty topological spaces, there is always a continuous function between the two, namely a constant one, but a continuous function that is not a homeomorphism does not admit a continuous inverse).
Turning to the homotopy relation between spaces, indeed one defines (after homotopy between functions) the notion of homotopy equivalence, which is already symmetrical (the homotopy inverse of a homotopy equivalence is itself a homotopy equivalence). My question is the following: in the context of homotopy relation between topological spaces, is there a notion which plays with respect to homotopy equivalence the same role that continuous functions play with respect to homeomorphisms? If this is not the case, I would be grateful to someone who would give hints to a possible explanation for the reason why this is not possible or not usually done.

Sure, it is the category of homotopy classes of continuous functions. When $X,Y$ are topological spaces, then for $f,g: X\to Y$ continuous, we say $f\sim g$ if the two maps are homotopic. This relation is an equivalence relation, and if $f_1,f_2:X\to Y$ and $g_1,g_2:Y\to Z,$ with $f_1\sim f_2, g_1\sim g_2$ then $g_1\circ f_1\sim g_2\circ f_2.$ So this means we have a category where the maps are homotopy classes, and the isomorphisms are the homotopy equivalences.

Continuous functions are the morphisms in $\mathbf{Top}$ and homeomorphisms are the isomorphisms in $\mathbf{Top}$, while (weak) homotopy equivalences are the isomorphisms in $Ho(\mathbf{Top})$, the homotopy category of $\mathbf{Top}$. So one possible answer is given by the morphisms in $Ho(\mathbf{Top})$, which are homotopy classes of continuous maps.

@ThomasAndrews Thank you, that is the setting I was looking for.

@NaïmFavier Thank you for your punctual remark.

One of the possible general frameworks that cover those cases, and many many more cases is co called category theory. Roughly speaking a category is a collection of objects, morphisms (a.k.a. arrows) between them, and a method of composing those morphisms (composition operator). One additional condition is that for each object $X$ there is the identity morphism $id_X:X\to X$ that satisfies some axioms.
Given a category $C$ a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is called an isomorphism, if there is a morphism $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g=id_Y$ and $g\circ f=id_X$.
Now topological spaces indeed form a category, together with continuous functions and standard function composition. In this category isomorphisms are precisely homeomorphisms.
We can construct another category out of it: given the set $C(X,Y)$ of all continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ we use our homotopy relationship $\sim$ and define $H(X,Y):=C(X,Y)/\sim$. We will now consider the collection of all topological spaces, but with elements of $H(X,Y)$ as morphisms. We also need to define composition operator, indeed, if $[f]\in H(X,Y)$ and $[g]\in H(Y,Z)$ then $[g]\circ [f]:=[g\circ f]$, where "$\circ$" on the right side is the standard composition of functions. One can show this is well defined.
In our new category morphisms are actually sets of morphisms. This is the beauty of category theory, that as long as something satisfies axioms it can be an object/arrow, regardless of what it really is (whatever that means). The point of all of that, is that it is straightforward to see that $f:X\to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence if and only if the corresponding $[f]$ is an isomorphism in our new category.
The presented category is known as naive homotopy category. There are other ways to define homotopy categories that have different interesting properties.
So that could be the end to the story, right? We just use equivalence classes instead of concrete functions.
But, you may ask: "Ok, but I'm dealing with homotopy equivalence map, I don't want to deal with entire equivalence class". Then of course it depends on what exactly you are looking for. But one such interpretation can be: is the naive homotopy category concrete? Roughly speaking concrete categories are those that can be represented as sets and functions between them. So for example the standard category of topological spaces and continuous functions between them is concrete.
Unfortunately, it is well known that naive homotopy category is not concrete. So in that sense, there is no way to replace continuous functions with something as good in the homotopy context. Homotopies are hard.

Thank you for the thorough and clear answer.
